# How to make samba4 use external LDAP for authN, internal LDAP for all else?

Tags: ldap, authentication, samba4

I have Samba v4.0.5 installed and running.  It is running its own 'bundled' ldap service.  I'm happy for it to use its own internal ldap service, but I'd like it to use an external ldap service for authentication.  Can someone tell me how to do that?  PAM?  Config statements in smb.conf?  Other?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Samba4 wiki](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/LDAP_Backend):

> This document attempts to describe some of requirements that a 'general purpose' LDAP directory server must meet to have Samba4 successfully use it as a 'directory backend'.
>
> ...
>
> **This is no longer an area of active development in Samba4, and is not supported, or expected to be supported**

I'd suggest switching whatever references your external LDAP to instead point to Samba4 (which implements AD) rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ntlm_auth](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/ntlm_auth.1.html). For example, both dovecot and squid support it.